# Billing distribution

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

What would be the best mathematical approach to devise a payment distribution method among three people for two separate billable services and if one of the three people did not use the services for the full billable period?

For example Service A had a total cost of 120 dollars , Service B had a total cost of 65 dollars. Service A had a total billing day cycle of 31 days, Service B had a total billing day cycle of 33 days. Out of the 3 people, only 1 used Services A and B for a total of 15 days, where as the other two individuals used Services A and B until the end of the billing cycle.

Would the best approach be splitting the cost in the following manner:

((days used / total days) * (total cost) / 3 people))

```
For that 1 person of 15 days:
Service A: ((15 / 31) * (120) / 3) = 19.35
Service B: ((15/33) * (65) / 3) = 9.85
```

Or

((Days used per individual / total days for all individuals) * total cost)

```
Service A: (15 / (15+31+31)) = 23.38
Service B: (15 / 15+33+33) = 12.04
```

Which of the two methods is better to use in terms of a more fair distribution?

Comment: I would guess the second one, because I would assume that the total cost is only for the days someone out of the 3 used it, and that they are not being charged for days no one used it.

Comment: Actually, can I ask a question? Why is the denominator the total of all days? 
I was just confused because the second interpretation is not something I personally use, since I use the first interpretation when splitting service bills.

I would appreciate your response.
Thank you!

Comment: I would guess that the total of all days would be used if the cost was the same for all days, regardless of whether someone used it or not those days. But, if it is only being billed for the days that someone used it and they don’t have to pay for days no one used it, you would use the second interpretation, because the cost would only be for the days the service was used. Also, the second interpretation makes it so that you have to pay more if you used the service more, which seems fairer. I hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh!
Thank you for your clear and concise explanation! That makes sense! Ok, I will go with the second interpretation based on what you have described.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how the billable service is charged. If the service has a fixed daily price independent of use (for example - unlimited internet at price 3.87 per day), then the first method is probably the fairest.  But if the service is charged by amount of 'stuff' used (for example gas used for cooking in a house at fixed price per kJ equivalent) **and** the three people each use similar amounts when they are cooking, then the second method is more reasonable.

Comment: Wow!

Thanks for your response!  You actually hit the nail on the coffin. The services I am attempting to calculate are for both internet and electricity (gas in your example).

I am just trying to think, if for example I know that one person used the stove for cooking more than another, would it be fair to implement the first method then?